# How do I get a valid date format from a string using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a source record that represents a date like this:

```
20151104
```

when I used Pig to load the source file, I defined the record like this:

```
data_raw = LOAD '/user/hue/myfile.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS 
(date:datetime)
```

Then use the following code to push it to a new format:

```
data_values = FOREACH data_raw GENERATE ToString(date, 'yyyyMMdd') AS   
date
```

When I dump the variable out, I get:

```
(201511040101)
```

Where is the 0101 coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input is not in ISO date and time formats.

Change input date to 20151104 to 2015-11-04, you will be able to see the expected result.

**Ref :**

> 1. http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
> 2. https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#datetime-functions

If you can read the input as String and if its in expected format then you need not do any conversion, if not make use of DateTime Functions to achieve the same.

**Update** : If you have Date as String in one format and you like to convert it to any other format then if you have to work with ToDate() and ToString() methods.

**N.B** : Return type of ToDate is DateTime object and that of ToString is String

> http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date
>   http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string

**Input :**

```
20151104
```

**PigScript :**

```
A = LOAD 'date_input'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (my_date:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(my_date, 'yyyyMMdd') AS  my_date;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ToString(my_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS my_date;
```

**Output :**

```
DUMP B :

(2015-11-04T00:00:00.000-08:00)

DUMP C :

(2015-11-04)
```

Comment: Other than changing the format in the source file, can [ToDate](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#subtract-duratioin) be used to convert it?

Comment: @andy : 1. Can the input date be read as chararray ? 2. Are you trying to update the input date from yyyyMMdd to any other format ? Update your usecase, based on the above two question.

Comment: Yes, it can be read in as a chararray and when converted using Todate(date,yyyyMMdd) yields the original string of 20151104.   Shouldn't it out as 2015-11-04?  Ultimately I want the non-ISO format to be converted to a nice ISO date value.

Comment: thank you @Murali Rao, that worked.  It seems the important thing is to match the pattern in the input during the ToDate operation format param.  For instance, if my input had been 9/22/2015, then to convert it to a valid ISO format my ToDate format param would be 'MM/dd/yyyy'.  Is that correct?

Comment: @andy : Yes your understanding is correct. There are overloaded versions of ToDate() method, the one which is used here is ToDate(String userstring, String format), in this case first input is the userstring and the second input is the format of the userstring.